# mysqldump --lock-all-tables

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I've been reading up on how to do mysql dumps / backups. 
It sounds like to ensure that you get all data, you really should run with the option --lock-all-tables.  What's not clear to me is if I need to run anything afterwards to unlock?

I'm going to try to run the following command:

> mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p DATABASENAME >
>   nameofdumpfile.sql

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the dump command completes it drops it's connection, also implicitly dropping any locks if not done explicitly.  So no, there's nothing separate you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the engine you're using.  Try InnoDB with the --single-transaction flag.